# C# database student project

Tags: c#, bindingnavigator

I am a current student and am working on a team project. We are building a medical DB using c# and access for the DB. I have been working on the "facesheet" and am experiencing a problem that I just can't seem to fix. Currently we use the binding navigator to add, delete, and browse the records, however, when you add new record the navigator shoots the record back to the first original record (if that makes sense).

I added this to the save button

```
private void patientInfoBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.patientInfoBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this._meddb_final_2000_DataSet);
    patientInfoTableAdapter.Update(this._meddb_final_2000_DataSet);
    this.patientInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this._meddb_final_2000_DataSet.PatientInfo);

}
```

Not sure if there is something I can do to stop the navigator from jumping back to the first record because it may confuse the medical students that will be using this program.

Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "shoots the record back to the first original record?" Do you mean to say that after saving the current record, the selection changes to the first record in the list?  If that's so, you can simply have a property that stores the current selection and after saving your record, make the selection equal your saved selection.  I'm not 100% sure how you have everything setup, though.

Comment: Yes it changes to the first record in the list. I am not too sure on how to set-up a property but is it just an option in visual studio?

Comment: ANother thing that is going on if you comment out last two lines. The record will stay on the one being added but as soon as you try to add any other info I get this                                                                 "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'PatientInfo'."

Comment: I don't think it would have to do anything with Visual Studio... since it's your program.  You really have to show us how you are constructing your program, because I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out what's going on there.  It could be that you reset your list and when you do that, the selection, which is not saved, becomes the very first index.  Just by looking at your code up there, it looks like you're re-filling the data, so that's probably what's going on.